# Get all the reports which have used a specific resource id of a domain topic in jasper

Tags: rest, jasperserver

I have created a topic using a Domain in my JasperReport Server. Now I need to get all the reports which have used that Domain or Topic by using REST API.

I have tried this REST call:

```
https://<host>/jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/resource/organizations/test/organizations/data/Reports?j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=jAspErAdmIn
```

It gives 200 OK. But no data, it only gives the login page source.

```
<title>TIBCO Jaspersoft: Login</title>
```

Can anyone tell me how how to get this from REST call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your call to the API seems errorneous.

According to [the docs](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/searching-repository) the call to the repository service looks like this:

```
http://<host>:<port>/jasperserver[-pro]/rest_v2/resources?<parameters>
```

In your case this would be:

```
http://<host>/jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/resources?<parameters>
```

Sencond, since your call is different, you won't get any result. It is possible to search for a specific string:

```
http://<host>/jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/resources?q=Domain_Name
```

and / or a type:

```
http://<host>/jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/resources?q=Domain_Name&type=dataType
```

As far as I understand it, it is not possible to search which report use which resources, though.